# Undefined index?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I changed my code for a few reasons which are irrelevant, but now I need your help again, since I'm very close on finishing one of first ''bigger'' projects in php and mysql, and I've changed my code to this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {


}

include('connect-with-mysql.php'); 

$Test1 = $_POST['test1']; 
$Test2 = $_POST['test2']; 
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO vanille"



?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Datenbank</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Überschrift</h1>
<form method="post" action="action.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<fieldset>
 <legend>New Ppl</legend>
 <label>Test1:<input type="text" name="test1" /></br>
 <label>Test2:<input type="text" name="test2" /></br>
</fieldset>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="add new informations" />    

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Here's the content of the connect-with-mysql.php file:

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root'); 
DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', ''); 
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'vanille'); 

$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME); 

?>
```

And then I'll get this error line:

Notice: Undefined index: test1 on line 11 (same with line 10)

Comment: `$_POST` will only be available if anything posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

you have closed the `if()`

Your database query, is open for `sql injection` and more over you will get errors if you run this query.

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

 include('connect-with-mysql.php'); // 

     $Test1 = $_POST['test1']; 
     $Test2 = $_POST['test2']; 
     $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO vanille"
 }

?>
```

Query should look like,

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO vanille (`test1`,`test2`) values ($Test1,$Test2)";

mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT INTO vanille (`test1`,`test2`) values ($Test1,$Test2)");
```

See this for [syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

I have shown the query for your reference, but make sure you use `PDO`

Comment: and how do i fix that?

Comment: for your reference i have changed the code of insert.

Comment: please share the content of `connect-with-mysql.php`.

Comment: i edited my question now you can see the content

Comment: i have changed my answer for insert, please check...

Comment: yes im doing that now

Comment: that shud come inside `if()`

Comment: so it should be like this: if ($sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO vanille (`test1`,`test2`) values ($Test1,$Test2)";

mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT INTO vanille (`test1`,`test2`) values ($Test1,$Test2)"); ?

Comment: no... im telling this line shud be inside `if(isset()){ post values //here  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93797/discussion-between-darkyagami-and-niranjan-n-raju).

Answer (score 0):

Once you request the page at initially stage it is not a post request. So, It will be get request and you are accessing array of $_POST which is not exist.
So, you got this error.Check that post array is present then go for accessing it's index.

```
<?php

 if (!empty($_POST)) {

     include('connect-with-mysql.php'); 

     $Test1 = $_POST['test1']; 
     $Test2 = $_POST['test2']; 
     $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO vanille"
 }

?>
```